# UItableViewCell with UIDatePicker : month column gets covered

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uidatepicker

UIDateTimePicker dropped on contentView of UITableViewCell in InterfaceBuilder Xcode 6.1 gets covered by white tiles. How to prevent it?

Comment: It's impossible. There is a bug in Xcode Interface Builder which makes all pickers created by visual tool in Xcode tailed with blank squares. For this version of Xcode the only solution which works it to create any pickers in the code !

Comment: holy #$!@ you gotta be kidding me. Create things in code now?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: This issue is resolved as of iOS9 beta 5. (2015.08.24)**

There seems to be a bug in UIDatePicker on iOS8. We just noticed this in Portrait mode on an iPad:
[image]

@BS4248 - Is this similar to what you're seeing? For us, the Hour column is missing instead of the Month column. It doesn't happen on any device running iOS7 and it doesn't happen on iPhones.

I was curious what was happening here so I set the background color of the datepicker to red in the debugger console:

```
expr [cell.datePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]
```

[image]

It seems that something is covering or breaking the Hour column in the datepicker, but after a couple hours trying to pick apart the picker I stumbled across something that fixes it for us. We had trailing and leading constraints set to stretch the UIDatepicker to the full width of the screen. When I deleted those it rendered correctly again:
[image]

And now when I set the background to red you can see it's much narrower:
[image]

Comment: Still not fixed in Xcode 6.2 (6C131e). Worse, when the only constraints are _Center X to Superview_ and _Center Y to Superview_ the bug is **not** avoided. I guess I will have to create the UIDatePicker in code instead of Storyboard.

Comment: I'm using pinned top-left corner and fixed height and width constraints and I still get this bug, I don't understand this answer, or at least cannot recreate it.

Comment: @Siegfoult - From what I can tell, the UIDatePicker needs to determine its own height/width or it doesn't draw correctly. Try removing the fixed size constraints.