# UIDatePicker hour column invisble/unscrollable in custom table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uidatepicker

I am using a custom table view cell with a UIDatePicker in it.  The auto layout dimensions on the UIDatePicker are fixed width and height (320x216) and pinned top-left corner.  This all works as expected, I'm just including these details in case they affect this problem.

The problem is that the date picker's Hour column is invisible and I cannot scroll it.  I can change it by tapping, but cannot see the changes in the picker itself, only read them off of the date property.  If the picker is set to Date+Time, the Day column's text is clipped on the right.

[image]

I suspect this is a glitch caused by having a date picker within a table view (since I think picker's are backed by table views) but I'm not sure how to fix it.

(Using iPad iOS 8.3.)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, seems to be the same issue as this, sorry for the duplicate:

[UItableViewCell with UIDatePicker : month column gets covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847618/uitableviewcell-with-uidatepicker-month-column-gets-covered?rq=1)

Still needs an answer... although it sounds like the answer is for Apple to fix it. :(